# MVC3 Routing gives 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have following entry in Global.asax:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Email",
            "Email/{emailId}",
            new { controller = "Email", action = "Index", emailId = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Details",
            "Details/{rmaid}/{orderid}",
            new { controller = "Details", action = "Index", rmaid = UrlParameter.Optional, orderid = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Logout", // Route name
            "Logout/", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Logout"} // Parameter defaults
        );
```

The very last for Logout is giving me 404.

My home Controller have following entry:

```
public ActionResult Logout()
        {
            Session.Abandon();
            return Redirect("/");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First enter your logout route and then the default route.
But if you don't use that logout route you could also navigate to Home/Logout.